# Xcode Analyze and Build skips every file

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am building a game using cocos2d-iphone 0.99.4 and Xcode 3.2.4.

When I try and and "build and analyze" the analyzer simply skips every file with various messages.

My files are all skipped for the following reason:

```
'/var/folders/kn/kn3feAZJGICNBebbEUEgS++++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/QSwitch_Prefix-efddpuqvkbtssoakbidmecjqikep/QSwitch_Prefix.pch' file not found
```

The cocos2d files are all skipped for a different reason:

```
expected function body after function declarator
expected a type
expected a type
expected a type
unknown type name "UIApplicationState"
expected a type
expected a type
expected a type
expected a type
unknown type name "UIDataDetectorTypes"
unknown type name "UIDataDetectorTypes"
```

I would post images but I don't have enough reputation points to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one of those weird Xcode bugs that really messes you up.  You could try making sure your certificates are valid, then starting with a clean slate by copying your files over to a new Xcode project.

This worked for someone with similar errors here:
http://osdir.com/ml/xcode-users/2010-09/msg00054.html

Comment: Having looked at that thread I changed my compiler type from gcc 4.2 to llvm gcc 4.2. This fixed the problem.